# CKEditor Automatic URL detection in IE8

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor 3.6 instance running.

In IE 8, when I type a URL, say, www.yahoo.com, CKEditor automatically detects that a URL is typed and converts it into a hyperlink like:

```
<a href="...">...</a>
```

My problem is that I am unable to find the source/code where this conversion is happening. How can I add `target="_blank"` by default to all the hyperlinks which are created?

Comment: You could just post-process the content and add it during save for example.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using dataprocessors

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    a: function( element ) {
                        element.attributes.target = '_blank';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
} );
```